# Matrix Ring of a Semisimple Ring

Tags: ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

I recently read the concept of semi-simplicity of a (not necessarily commutative) ring.

A ring $R$ is said to be semi-simple if $R$ as a left module over itself is a semi-simple module (This in turn means that each submodule (i.e, left ideal) of $R$ is a direct summand for $R$.)

I am grappling with the following question:

> If $R$ is semi-simple, then so is the matrix ring $M_n(R)$.

It is a theorem that each left module of a semi-simple ring is a semi-simple module. Thus $M_n(R)$ is a semi-simple module of $R$. But this doesn't help me.

I need to show that each left ideal of $M_n(R)$ is a direct summand for $M_n(R)$. Is there a characterization  of the left ideals of $M_n(R)$ in terms of the left ideals of $R$?

Lastly, does the converse also hold?

> If $M_n(R)$ is a semi-simple ring, then is $R$ necessarily a semi-simple ring?

Thanks.

Comment: It might help to start by showing that $M_n(R)$ decomposes, as a left module over itself, as a direct sum of $n$ copies of the module $R^n$, then trying to figure out what the submodules of $R^n$ are. And the converse holds. In fact 1) a ring is semisimple iff its category of modules is semisimple, which means e.g. that submodules of modules are always direct summands, and 2) $R$ and $M_n(R)$ have equivalent categories of modules (they are *Morita equivalent*).

Comment: Thank you. Need time to digest your answer.

Comment: May you provide more steps please?! If $S=M_n(R)$ (for instance) then $S=e_{11}S+e_{22}S$, where $e_{11}$ is the matrix whose $(1,1)$-entry is $1$ and $0$ otherwise. We define $e_{22}$ analogously. Clearly, $e_{11}S \cong R^2$ and $e_{22}S \cong R^2$. What next ? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: When $R$ is a domain (not necessarily commutative), the answer is positive, and we can even conclude that $R$ is actually a division ring. One may turn to **Ex. 3.2** (with a solution there) of https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3987-9 for a proof.

Comment: well, if you are ever talking about a  commutative ring which is semisimple then it will be nothing but direct product of fields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show that for any simple left ideal $S \subseteq R$ and index $j$
$$R_{S, j} = \left\{A \in M_n(R) \ \middle| \ A_{ij} \in S \ \text{and} \ A_{ik} = 0 \ \forall i, k \neq j\right\}$$
is a simple left ideal in $M_n(R)$ and as a module over itself $M_n(R)$ is the direct sum of these when $S$ varies over all simples and $j$ varies over all indices.

Comment: Thank you. Reflecting on your answer.

Comment: I didn't get it. May you provide more steps and clarifications please? @Jim